# Can I transition one pie chart into a different one using a fade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts v.2.3.3 and have built a pie chart. When a user clicks on something, I can replace that chart with a different one, but the replacing happens instantaneously. Is there a way to have the first pie chart fade out while the new pie chart fades in, so there is a "blur" effect?

Note: the first pie chart currently gets deleted before the new chart gets built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I used jquery to clone the svg element of the first chart and appended it to a div that was absolutely positioned over the chart area. I then used that "dummy" chart for the fade out animation without needing to fade in the second chart.

```
var clonedChart = $('#chartContainer').find('svg').clone();
$('<div class="cloned_chart"></div>').append(clonedChart).appendTo('#pieChartWrapper');

// delete first chart and create second one
....

// chart creation callback
$('.cloned_chart').fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would fade out the current chart container using jquery like so :

```
$('#ChartContainer').fadeOut();
```

Then I would replace the chart with the new one and use jquery 
fadeIn() to bring the chart back into view.

**EDIT**

The jquery fadeOut/fadeIn function's first parameter is an optional speed parameter, so you could time the animations so they "blur" together.

Comment: Thanks @Robotsushi, but I can't have any whitespace showing in the transition between the two. I think I am going to try a different route and clone the svg element that gets created, append to the container's parent, and use that to fade out as a "dummy" chart while the real chart gets deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The only issue with that is that the old chart gets destroyed and completely removed from the DOM before the second gets built, so the fade in would seem kinda strange and I had to clone the chart so I could wait until after the fade to remove all traces of it.